# Formatting time in Flutter (Dart)

Tags: android, flutter, time, dart-pub

Is there any way to get time of different timezones or countries without using "time API" , below shown is what I already tried, but I don't know what is wrong here.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a [timezone](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) package to achieve this. You can simply get the location and timezone with this:

```
  import 'package:timezone/standalone.dart' as tz;

  Future<void> setup() async {
    await tz.initializeTimeZone();
    var detroit = tz.getLocation('America/Detroit');
    var now = tz.TZDateTime.now(detroit);
  }
```

Comment: I tried still something is wrong with my code , please tell me what is wrong here